# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/facebook/drawee/backends/pipeline/info/ImagePerfDataListener;

Tags: android, react-native, facebook, crash, crash-reports

Once i intall the app in the android device, once i try to open it, it suddenly crashes and closes. always having same issue even though i did reset-cache and gradlew clean.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/facebook/drawee/backends/pipeline/info/ImagePerfDataListener;
 at com.gestorum.ReactNativeFlipper.initializeFlipper(ReactNativeFlipper.java:33)
 at com.gestorum.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:60)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1190)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6582)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:224)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1887)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.info.ImagePerfDataListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.gestorum-SB2v2uWfMrjH0B3TmmtzKg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.gestorum-SB2v2uWfMrjH0B3TmmtzKg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.gestorum-SB2v2uWfMrjH0B3TmmtzKg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:230)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
 ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to check out my short write-up in [facebook/react-native#41937 (comment)](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/41937#issuecomment-1862698593).
In essence:

> […] [ReactNativeFlipper.kt:14](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blame/1045b225f1a1ab1150b3e8732820c8cecd3e04c2/packages/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/flipper/ReactNativeFlipper.kt#L14) mentions:
>
> ```java
> /**
> * Stub class that does nothing to ease the migration out of Flipper. Users should stop calling
> * `ReactNativeFlipper.initializeFlipper` in their `MainApplication.java` as this class will be
> * removed in React Native 0.75 or future versions.
> */
> ```
>
> And indeed, if the `ReactNativeFlipper.initializeFlipper()` line in
> `MainApplication.java` is commented-out, the issue is resolved.

Hope it works for you.